# How to get all value from multiple dictionary with same value into list python

Tags: python

i would like to make list like below

```
data2 = ['Run, Read', 'Sing, Read', 'Run, Sing, Read', 'Read']
```

from this list

```
data = [
{29: 'Run'}, 
{29: 'Read'}, 
{30: 'Sing'}, 
{30: 'Read'}, 
{31: 'Run'}, 
{31: 'Sing'}, 
{31: 'Read'}, 
{32: 'Read'}]
```

can anyone help me

Comment: return code is `['Run', 'Read', 'Sing', 'Read', 'Run', 'Sing', 'Read', 'Read']`

Comment: but i want to return data like this `['Run, Read', 'Sing, Read', 'Run, Sing, Read', 'Read']`

Comment: when key in dictionary is same value with same key will be join into 1 index in new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People, please read the question correctly.
The OP is asking how to collect the strings of different dicts with the same key into a single string.

I am a bit wondering how you would end up with a list of dicts like that, and not something like

```py
data = [
{29: 'Run', 30: 'Sing', 31: 'Read', 32: 'Read'}, 
{29: 'Read', 30: 'Read', 31: 'Run'},
{31: 'Sing')]
```

which is basically the same, but that is besides the point.

You can easily do what you want with the following:

```py
data = [
{29: 'Run'}, 
{29: 'Read'}, 
{30: 'Sing'}, 
{30: 'Read'}, 
{31: 'Run'}, 
{31: 'Sing'}, 
{31: 'Read'}, 
{32: 'Read'}]

# Create empty dict for all keys
key_dct = {}

# Loop over all dicts in the list
for dct in data:
    # Loop over every item in this dict
    for key, value in dct.items():
        # Add value to the dict with this key
        key_dct.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

# Combine all items in key_dct into strings
data2 = [', '.join(value) for value in key_dct.values()]

# Print data2
print(data2)
```

Output: `['Run, Read', 'Sing, Read', 'Run, Sing, Read', 'Read']`

Note that my solution works even if some of the dicts contain more than a single item.

EDIT: If you want to be certain that the order of the strings are also in the numerical order of the keys, then replace the creation of `data2` in the snippet above with

```py
# Sort items on their key values
items = list(key_dct.items())
items.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

# Combine all items into strings
data2 = [', '.join(value) for _, value in items]
```

Comment: nice code but when i run this code, the result like this `['Read', 'Run,Read', 'Sing,Read', 'Run,Sing,Read'] ` what happen in my code, could i sort it?

Comment: @AkhmadAli Ah, then you are probably using Python 3.5 or earlier, when ordered dicts were not the standard dict yet.
I can modify my answer to make sure that the values are in the correct order as well without adding dependencies.

Comment: oh im sorry i miss to tell python version what i use

Comment: im using python 2.7.9

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice @1313e

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)** to put the same key value inside a list and then concatenate those value.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k].append(v)

result = [", ".join(value) for _, value in result.items()]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['Run, Read', 'Sing, Read', 'Run, Sing, Read', 'Read']
```

Comment: This will not work if any of the dicts in `data` contains more than a single item.

Comment: @1313e added an extra loop for handling the same.

Comment: And now our answers are basically the same. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like:

```
data2 = [list(d.values())[0] for d in data]
```

Comment: What if `{29: 'Run', 30: 'XXX'}`

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Why would {29: 'Run', 30: 'XXX'} be a problem?

Comment: You are taking the first element from the values list(d.values())`[0]`